# Orthogonal Connector Routing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-structures

I'm trying to implement orthogonal connectors between rectangles. Rectangles are inside canvas. I found this document http://users.monash.edu/~mwybrow/papers/wybrow-gd-2009.pdf . This is  what I need but I don't understand how to generete "interesting horizontal segments" (or vertical). Here is my c# code.

```
        foreach (var item in this.AllItems.OfType<DesignerItemViewModel>())
        {
            #region Boundaries

            graph.AddVertex(new Point(item.Left, item.Top), null);
            graph.AddVertex(new Point(item.Left + item.Width, item.Top), null);
            graph.AddVertex(new Point(item.Left, item.Top + item.Height), null);
            graph.AddVertex(new Point(item.Left + item.Width, item.Top + item.Height), null);

            #endregion

            #region Connectors

            graph.AddVertex(ItemHelper.GetPointForConnector(item.LeftConnector), null);
            graph.AddVertex(ItemHelper.GetPointForConnector(item.TopConnector), null);
            graph.AddVertex(ItemHelper.GetPointForConnector(item.RightConnector), null);
            graph.AddVertex(ItemHelper.GetPointForConnector(item.BottomConnector), null);

            #endregion

            #region Horizontal segments

            // how to create this?
            // graph.AddEdge(...);

            #endregion
        }
```

edit:

[Actually implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfKlY.png)

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP9Gl.png)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm not even sure I follow what you're asking. Have you used Visio? It has points appear half way on each edge of a rectangle and you draw lines between them. Those could be adorners in a wpf app. Maybe that's relevant, maybe not.

Comment: I am not sure if this solution is exactly what need. I edited my question.

Comment: You mean your problem is gettting from one point to another without collision?

Comment: Yes. "Orthogonal Visibility Graph" should resolved this issue but I don't know how to generate vertical / horizontal segments.

1. Generate the interesting horizontal segments HI
2. Generate the interesting vertical segments VI 
3. Compute the orthogonal visibility graph by intersecting all pairs of segments from HI and VI .

these 3 steps should be solution but i don understand

Comment: Your assumption here is that people will read through that paper you linked, understand it and work out what your question means. You will be lucky if anyone does that.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the core of this question is how to work out where the shapes are so you can work out how to avoid them.
These are all rectangles, and it seems your lines are all going to be horizontal or vertical.
That makes collision avoidance much simpler.

You could just iterate the children of the canvas to get a reference to all the rectangles.
Maybe that's inconvenient for whatever reason.
Clearly you have a DesignerItemViewModel ( vm ) which presumably corresponds to each of the rectangles.
Bind or set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top of that to properties.
You have the point defining the top left corner then.
Bind height and width.
Calculate the points for all corners from that.
You can then work out the vertical and horizontal lines you don't want a connector to cross.
And you can do that for everything by iterating the list of vm.
If your connector has to go past the x co-ordinate of one of these and it's y is within the top and bottom y then you need to re-route.
Working out that re-routing could be done by calculating which is closer, the top of bottom.
Add some number to that so your line is separate from the existing rectangle.
You then have the y to use for the line.

Obviously, there is a fair bit more to doing this but I think iterating that collection and working out any collisions is probably what is meant by that calculating the orthogonal visibility graph and intersecting pairs.
I may be totally wrong  - I didn't read the technical paper.